# Android: TCP/IP-Server of just using GCM

Tags: java, android, tcp, google-cloud-messaging

I wrote an app with TCP/IP-connection to my TCP/IP-Server as a Messaging-app.

Now I wonder, if I could just use GCM to forward my messages from client-to-server and server-to-client?

Why still need an own tcp/ip-Connection?

Or is there a mistake in my way of thinking? Should I just use GCM to handle keepAlive-Messages of my tcp/ip-Connection.

Can I implement a appserver for receiving GCM-Messages in my Java-Tcp/ip-Server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the GCM only works in one direction.

What you can do it have your server take a POST from your clients. Then verify their identity and use the GCM to send the message to all clients on the topic they are trying to reach.